# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int' error in Python Pandas group by operation

Tags: python, pandas

Has anyone seen and/or understand the below error I encounted in pandas when doing a value_counts operation on a column that I verified has only numbers represented as string objects? Trying to identify what is causing this; first time I have ever seen this.

```
col1
3234
2334
4342
...
```

`df[col1].value_counts()` returns

`<repr(<pandas.core.series.Series at 0x819a0d0>) failed: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'>`

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been related to my display.max_rows setting which I had set to "None." When I reverted back to default 60 then I was able to do the groupby on the column.

Comment: this issue (the None in the max_rows setting), is fixed in 0.14.0 (0.14rc1 is out, FYI): https://github.com/pydata/pandas/releases